# Babylonjs Mesh physics imposter collision

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm making minecraft with babylon.js. I made object, then set mesh physics imposter.I also set player's physics imposter as sphere imposter. However, they dont collide and player just goes through map.

map is made manually, like the code below.

```
newVertices.push(x,y-1,z);
    newVertices.push(x,y,z);
    newVertices.push(x+1,y,z);
    newVertices.push(x+1,y-1,z);
    Cube(b);//add vertices then create face etc.
```

I set to update physics imposter every time map model is updated(when block is placed or removed)

```
mesh.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(mesh, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.MeshImpostor, {restitution:0}, scene);
```

How can I make these collide? Please help me. thanks.

Comment: did you enbled physics in the scene with `scene.enablePhysics();` ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Yes,of course I did it, and gravity works with player.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini That's how interception is made

Comment: @ProJser can you post more of your code? I'd be happy to look it over. In the meantime- here's a bowling game I made you can check out for an example. (press 's' to bowl) 

[link to game](http://taylorthedeveloper.github.io/Babylon/bowling.html)
[src](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TaylorTheDeveloper/TaylorTheDeveloper.github.io/master/Babylon/bowling.html)